# Neural Network Librosa Import Error Python Tensorflow

Tags: python, librosa

I have attempted to construct a Python program in order to complete an experiment whereby neural networks with varying layers attempt to identify the composer of a particular piece of classical music. This program is being run on the Macintosh Mojave system. In order to assist my efforts, I have attempted to derive some information from a particular source:

https://medium.com/@navdeepsingh_2336/identifying-the-genre-of-a-song-with-neural-networks-851db89c42f0

Unfortunately however, I have faced a series of setbacks in the completion of this project. I have most recently encountered one error.
The program I ran in a `Python 3.6` file was a series of imports, where an error was reached due to a librosa import, even though librosa was installed at the time:

```
import librosa
import librosa.feature
import librosa.display
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

The error message given by Python:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/surengrigorian/Documents/Stage1.py", line 1, in 
>   import librosa ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'

When I attempted to check whether librosa had been installed or not, the Mac OS terminal gave this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: librosa in         /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.38.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from librosa) (0.42.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from librosa) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from librosa) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.12 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from librosa) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn!=0.19.0,>=0.14.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from librosa) (0.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: resampy>=0.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from librosa) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: audioread>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from librosa) (2.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from librosa) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from librosa) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite>=0.27.0dev0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.38.0->librosa) (0.27.0)
```

Comment: You say you ran the file with `python3.6` but librosa is installed in `python3.7`. You have multiple versions of python installed. Try running `python3.7 filename.py`

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `keras` or `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: I recently deleted Python 3.7 in order to use Python 3.6.

Comment: What is the output of `pip --version` ?